# Using object destructuring to require() Express Router

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, destructuring, express-router

This code works:

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();

Router.get('/hello-world', (req, res, next) => {                                     
    res.send("hello world!"); //works great                   
});
```

But this code doesn't:

```
const {Router} = require('express');

Router.get('/hello-world', (req, res, next) => {                                     
    res.send("hello world!"); // :( doesnt work                  
});
```

What am I misunderstanding about destructuring? Thanks

Comment: Object Destructuring wont work as Router is a function. If the require module had a property Router then it can be accessed in the way you have coded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still need to call the function:

```
const {Router} = require('express');
Router().get('/hello-world', (req, res, next) => {
//    ^^
    res.send("hello world!"); // :( doesnt work                  
});
```

> What am I misunderstanding about destructuring?

The code

```
const {Router} = require('express');
```

is equivalent to

```
const temp = require('express');
const Router = temp.Router;
```

but you were doing

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();
//                           ^^
```